# Webform-civicrm Address fields not being saved in CiviCRM

Tags: webform-civicrm

We are running Civi 4.7.29. with Drupal. We have a webform using Drupal webform integration which populates civicrm fields.  When the form is submitted the address fields (Street, State, Postal Code, Country) are not being saved in CiviCRM.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue in the code: https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/137/files (It is a one line change)

Above is from a Pull Request and that Pull Request is not merged after discussing it because it is caused by a regression bug in CiviCRM core which is fixed in a newer version of CiviCRM. So the other solution is upgrading your CiviCRM.

Answer (score 2):

Are the affected fields selected in the "Fields to lock' dropdown in the "CONTACT FIELD HANDLING" section of the "Existing Contact" field of the webform?

IF so, then see this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2769423). At the bottom is a link to a much-needed pull request which has been available since Dec 2016. I don't know why it was never merged. With each update of webform_civicrm, I apply the third commit in that PR. Not sure of the importance of the first two commits shown there.